# Ten men selected to include a captain vs ten men selected to include at least one officer

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation

I can't see how these are different scenarios, but the answers are different.

The general scenario is that there is a company of volunteers that consists of a captain, a lieutenant, an ensign, and eighty rank and file.

> **Q1** In how many ways can ten men be selected as to include the captain?

We select the captain in 1 ways and then we choose 9 out of remaining 82. So 82 choose 9.

> **Q2** In how many ways can ten men be selected so as to include at least one officer?

The answer claims we find all the ways of choosing 10 out of 83 and then subtract the 10 out of 80 ways in which we only choose members of the 80 rank and file.

Why would the second scenario be any different than the first?  Don't we just select an officer and then choose 9 from 82 to fill the other spots and satisfy the given condition?

Comment: (i) officer is not the same as captain; (ii) you are multiple counting the choices that have more than one officer.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly: if we have (1) a selection that includes a captain, lieutenant, and an ensign, and (2) a selection that includes a lieutenant and an ensign, those only count for 1 selection in our tally?

Comment: @ChaseBanta Not quite.  He means, if you do it as: step1(choose an officer first), step2(choose 9 additional people) winds up counting the scenario of choosing step1(cap) step2(lt and rank&file 1-8) in addition to step1(lt) step2(cap and rank&file 1-8) separately, but to us they are the same scenario.

Comment: You did not say explicitly what answer you had in mind, but it sounds like you are thinking of $\binom{3}{1}\binom{82}{9}$. This would double-count all squads that had the captain, the lieutenant, and the rest rank and file. For it counts as different captain as "first" choice, lieutenant later, and lieutenant as "first" choice, captain later.

Comment: As a side note, often times when you see the phrase, "at least", it will involve finding the complement ("none, or no ways") and subtracting that out of something.

Comment: Think of it as (num ways with no requirements) = (num ways with zero officers) + (num ways with exactly 1 officer) + (num ways with exactly 2 officers) + (num ways with exactly 3 officers) = (num ways with zero officers) + (num ways with *at least* 1 officer).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  It makes sense now.  Especially helpful to think of subtracting the compliment of the event of interest from the total number of events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is between **exactly one** and **at least one**.

When you need **exactly one** captain in addition to nine others, you first choose the one captain ($1$ way of doing this), and then you choose nine non-captains ($82 \choose 9$ ways of doing this).

Similarly, if you need **exactly one** officer, then you can first choose the officer ($3$ ways), and then choose nine non-officers ($80 \choose 9$ ways).

But if you need **at least one** officer you can't do this.
You might think that you can choose the first officer ($3$ ways) and then choose nine other people ($82 \choose 9$ ways).
But this *overcounts* in scenarios where there are more than one officer in the group.  For instance, consider the situation where you have the captain, the ensign, and $8$ non-officers.  You will count this situation twice; once by first picking the captain and then picking the 9 others, and once by first picking the ensign and then picking the 9 others.  But you only want to count this situation once.

The correct way to do **at least one** is as the book suggests; take all the ways of doing a group of $10$ ($83 \choose 10$) and subtract the ones with exactly zero officers ($80 \choose 10$).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Goos.  Since you seem to know the book I'm reading from (Choice and Chance by Whitworth, for those that don't know but are interested), do you think its a good text to be learning from, or do you have a different suggestion?

Comment: @ChaseBanta Ha, I actually don't know the book.  When I read your question I apparently assumed you were working out of some book, but now I look back I realize you didn't mention it.